# Parts of the Quark Wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quarks

Quarks are fermions meaning that they have an antisymmetric wavefunction. Under particle exchange the sign of the wavefunction.

The wavefunction is made up of a few different parts
$$
\psi_{Total} = \psi_{Space}\psi_{Spin}\psi_{Flavour}\psi_{Colour}
$$

My notes explain that $\psi_{Space}$ is symmetric, and $\psi_{Spin}\psi_{Flavour}$ is symmetric, so we can conclude $\psi_{Colour}$ is antisymmetric, but why can we say the above two things about $\psi_{Spin}\psi_{Flavour}$ and $\psi_{Colour}$?

Comment: This may be unanswerable without access to the notes.

Comment: It's more a question of just why are some parts of the wavefunction symmetric and others aren't? I shouldn't have mentioned the notes.

Comment: Then it depends on the situation. Some states are space-symmetric and some are space-asymmetric, and so on. The inference is *if* space and  (spin and flavour) are symmetric, *then* the colour part must be asymmetric.

Comment: So determining which parts of the wave function are symmetric/anti-symmetric depends entirely on the situation we're in?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.